# Shared pointers in multi-threaded environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, shared-ptr

I have code something like this:

```
    vectorOfSharedPointers.resize(limit);

    parallelLoop(index, 0 , limit, increment = 1){ //process all the elements in parallel

            boost::shared_ptr<ClassA> ptrA;

            ptrA.reset(new ClassA(ref1, ref2, ostreamRef1, ostreamRef2)); // creates object of ClassA and assigns it to ptrA

            ptrA->setSomeAttribute(ref3); // calls some function on the object

            vectorOfSharedPointers[index] = ptrA; // this vector is class variable

    }

    for(int i =0 ; i<limit ; i++){

            boost::shared_ptr<ClassA> ptr  = vectorOfSharedPointers[i];

            ptr->someFunction();

    }
```

ostreamRef1 and ostreamRef2 are references of ostream type pointing to variables of type std::ostringstream and created as  [std::ostringstream strStream;].

The first time this code is called everything works fine. The second time it is called, ptr->someFunction(), this functions throws segmentation fault as *ostreamRef1* is null. I am not calling close() on it anywhere. *ostreamRef1* is found to be null inside **someFunction**() only, when I checked it inside this code block it was not null at the instance **someFunction**() is called. My doubt is why is it not valid inside **someFunction**() but valid in this code block before and after **someFunction**() is called.

I think possible culprit could be: multithreading, shared_ptr, combination of both.

What could be the possible reason and solution?

Comment: You don't show enough to be able to say, but if you're modifying the `shared_ptr` in two different threads, you'll need to provide some sort of synchronization.

Comment: if `vectorOfSharedPointers` is a `std::vector<...>` you'll need a `std::mutex` to control access to it during your parallel loop.

Comment: I tried removing multi-threading still it's crashing.

Comment: This question needs a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Please let me know what more details you want on this. :)